# Is there a not or only function in python, if so how would it be used?

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to python and haven't been using it for ages but I'm trying to make an if decision work and it needs a not or ONLY function to work correctly here is the code:

```py
    primechecker=input('Input a number, ill check if its prime: ')
    for k in range(1,1001):
        if int(primechecker)/int(k) == int(primechecker) or int(primechecker)/int(k) == 1:
            print('The number is prime!')
        else: 
            print('Number not prime.')
```

as you can see it needs some sort of line that says `if primechecker/k == ONLY 1 or primechecker` print its prime.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help please read this

Comment: Please use triple backticks to highlight your code. Also please read the guidelines.

Comment: Check the logic of your code again. There is nothing in your code that checks if your number is actually divisible by `k`. "`n` is only divisible by 1 and `n`" can't be expressed like you do.

Comment: There are a number of algorithms for finding primes.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes is simple to implement.   Such a language feature *might* be nice to have, but unfortunately, it doesn't really exist.

Comment: @edd313 What am I supposed to read here exactly? Did I ask a question wrong or break a rule I didn't know about?

Comment: No rules broken but you can now see how your question could have been improved. The help has got good advice on how to ask good questions, which also means that your you are much more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such function unfortunately. You have to do this yourself with iteration:

```
# You can convert to an int here
num = int(input('Input a number, ill check if its prime: '))

# Assume number is prime
prime = True
# Need to check from 2 onwards. Number in range are already ints
for k in range(2, num):
    # If the remainder of num divided by k is 0
    if num % k == 0:
        print('The number is not prime')
        prime = False
        # Break leaves the for loop
        break

if prime == True:
    print("Number is prime")
```

You need to use a buffer variable `prime` to assume it is prime, then change it later on if you find out it is not prime.

---

A simple example checking what's in a list:

```py
x = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]

# Check to see if the only number in x is 1
for number in x:
    if number != 1:
        print("There is a number that is not 1 in here")
        # This leaves the for loop
        break
```